# Saving files with iOS. Where do they go?

Tags: ios, file-io

I have saved a text file from my app and I can open it again, but is there any way the user can gain access to this file to just do whatever they want with it? I tried printing the path which looks like this : `/var/mobile/Applications/2DD5A15B-9BC8-4981-A1F6-E22F66C71CA4/Documents/` I'm assuming that huge number is some type of app identifier, which leads me to believe that this file isn't going to be accessible unless you're in the app. Which makes me wonder, why would writing a file be any better than just saving a big string to NSUserDefaults?

I am building an app where the user should be able to do some data logging. If the user can sync their phone with their computer and download the file that would be awesome. Can you do that? Or do I have to build in functionality so that they have to email themselves the file or something?

Comment: [How do I export text from iOS application to desktop PC?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7019813)

Comment: It sounds like perhaps the iCloud backup services would do what you are asking.

Comment: Connect your device to your developing pc, go to xcode - organizer - devices - apps, there you can see where the files live. Or use the simulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm assuming that huge number is some type of app identifier

It is. It's an [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier).

> which leads me to believe that this file isn't going to be accessible unless your in the app

...unless *you are* in the app (**or,** unless the device is jailbroken, in which case it's plaintext for anyone interested).

> why would writing a file be any better than just saving a big string to NSUserDefaults

Conceptually, it's not a setting. If you have some data, an entity, then write it to a file. `NSUserDefaults` is not appropriate for storing large amounts of data. It's for storing user preferences (which are volatile!), nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

made of the concept of iOS this is also called sandboxing.
if this would not exist, it could be possible to change or getting data of other apps.

Answer (score 0):

`If the user can sync their phone with their computer and download the file that would be awesome. Can you do that? Or do I have to build in functionality so that they have to email themselves the file or something?`

you can use the awesome iCloud.
check here:https://developer.apple.com/icloud/index.php