# Can't Find CSV file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, csv

I'm trying to build an app that is a survey that saves the text-filled data to a CSV file which can then be emailed at a later date.
I have followed a few tutorials online and came up with an app that works however has a few problems (see my coding below).

In the view .m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize first;
@synthesize seconds;
@synthesize tel;
@synthesize resultview;

- (IBAction)retractkeyboard:(id)sender{
    [self resignFirstResponder];
}

-(IBAction)saveinfo:(id)sender{
    NSString *resultLine=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@,%@\n",
                          self.first.text,
                          self.seconds.text,
                          self.tel.text];
    NSString *docPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];
    //resultview.text = docPath;
    NSString *surveys=[docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"results.csv"];

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:surveys]) {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager]
         createFileAtPath:surveys contents:nil attributes:nil];
    }
    NSFileHandle *filehandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:surveys];
    [filehandle seekToEndOfFile];
    [filehandle writeData:[resultLine dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [filehandle closeFile];
    self.first.text=@"";
    self.seconds.text=@"";
    self.tel.text=@"";
    NSLog(@"info saved");
}

-(IBAction)retrieveinfo:(id)sender{
    NSString *docPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];
    //resultview.text = docPath;
    NSString *surveys=[docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"results.csv"];

    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: surveys])
    {
        NSFileHandle *filehandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:surveys];
        NSString *surveyresults=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:[filehandle availableData] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [filehandle closeFile];
        self.resultview.text=surveyresults;
}
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

And in the view .h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *first;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *seconds;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *tel;
-(IBAction)saveinfo:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)retrieveinfo:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)retractkeyboard:(id)sender;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *resultview;

@end
```

My problem is: the app is telling me that the data is saved to the .csv file but I can't seem to find it anywhere? (I have even gone into the mac's library folder, etc, but find everything else apart from the file) I know it's saving it but have no idea where! Also the load function isn't working but I feel this is due to the fact that it can't load the file due to the fact that it's not there. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put in some NSLog statements to see exactly where the file is:

```
NSLog(@"surveys path: %@", surveys);
```

Here is the error:

```
Incorrect: `NSDocumentationDirectory`   
Correct:   `NSDocumentDirectory`
```

`surveys` is a terrible name for a file path and will cause confusion, something like `surveysPath` would be a lot better.

You can use the debugger to add breakpoints, follow the execution and examine the variable's values. Debugging is a necessary skill to learn and become proficient at—unless you can write correct code the first time 100% of the time.

Tip: Best practive is DRY (Don't Repeat Youself), create a method to return the path, taking the file name as an argument. Sure it is only has a couple of lines but there is only one place to update.

Example code:

```
- (NSString *)documentPathForFileName:(NSString *)fileName {
    NSString *documentFolderPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject];
    NSString *filePath = [documentFolderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    return filePath;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this I have found where the csv is being saved which is 
2014-08-28 16:54:16.179 test[11669:60b] surveys path: /Users/davemckenzie/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/993A4C49-705B-49CC-945D-B76C479F4B0D/Library/Documentation/results.csv
However I get to Library and there is no documentation folder? Just Caches and Preferences?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this on a Mac through the simulator?  You say it's iOS.  If you're running on the Sim, you'll find the files in ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/X.X/Applications/XXX/

Where the X.X is the iOS version running on the sim, and XXX is some hash which the sim uses to place it's files (you'll have to look through the folders to find your app.

Comment: Yes Im using the i-phone simulator on the mac, I have found my folder with Applications etc however I still cant find the text file? Everything else is there...? I thought it would appear in the documents in there or something? Its not a fault with my code then?

Comment: Documents folder would be: NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocument, ... You're using the DocumentationFolder  (Documentation)

Answer (score 0):

If your using a phone look at this:

[How do I export text from iOS application to desktop PC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019813/how-do-i-export-text-from-ios-application-to-desktop-pc)

In the plist you have to add an attribute:
Application supports iTunes file sharing

And then you can view the file from iTunes.