# How to transfer ios app generated data to macbook?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, ibeacon

My app scans BLE beacons nearby and estimate their RSSI values. I need those RSSI values on my macbook for further analysis. Is it possible to transfer and store those RSSI values on macbook during run time of the app.

Comment: Have you looked into Handoff and AirDrop? Writing all those values into a file and air dropping them to your mac should work.

Comment: Is there any way to save the data in .txt file inside macbook during runtime? The iOS device will be connected with macbook via data cable.

Comment: No I don't think so. This would require you to be able to access mac's drive and that would be a security issue. Maybe some private API could do this, but I'm not sure. Other thing to consider is to setup a server on your mac, and have the app upload data to it. Then the server can save it to files on the mac.

Comment: From the top of my head: you have access to the sandbox when the app stopped.  In Xcode go to the Organizer (I think) where you see your device (above all the other simulators), choose your app from the list, click the gear icon at the bottom and either browse the sandbox or copy it to your machine and browse it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use iTunes or email to transfer your data to your macbook. Please follow the following link [How do I export text from iOS application to desktop PC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019813/how-do-i-export-text-from-ios-application-to-desktop-pc) . Hope it helps.